# What would be the direct equivalent for FULL OUTER JOIN on SparkSQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to translate a SQL Server query to SparkSQL. What would be the direct translation for the FULL OUTER JOIN operation ?

Answer (score 0):

The same recipe, the same syntax.

Full Join

A full join returns all values from both relations, appending NULL values on the side that does not have a match. It is also referred to as a full outer join.

Syntax:

relation FULL [ OUTER ] JOIN relation [ join_criteria ]